# Seam: Validation of s:fileUpload?

Tags: validation, jsf, file-upload, richfaces, seam

I've got a JSF page that allows users to upload images.  I'd like to perform some validation on the uploaded file to ensure it's the correct size, dimensions, content type, etc.  I've created a JSF Validator, and have tried specifying it both in the `<s:fileUpload validator="XXX" />` attribute, as well as using the `<f:validator />` tag.  However, no matter what I try my validator is never called.  Is there any way to validate a file upload in Seam?  Would using `<rich:fileUpload />` allow me to do validation on the uploaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I've just decided to do a manual validation in my submit method.  I haven't found a way to get a Validator object to work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a listener like (not sure if event has a cancel method to call if your constraint fails, but you can check):

```
public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();

    String name = "unnamed_attachment";
    byte[] data = item.getData();

    if (item.isFile()) {
        name = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getFileName());
        data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray( item.getFile() );
    }

    debug("file uploaded '#0' : '#1'", name, item.getFileName());
```

And some constraints you can put in components.xml, like:

`<web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="false" 
                          max-request-size="5200000" 
                          url-pattern="/*"/>`

Comment: I've used a listener for <rich:fileUpload /> before, but never <s:fileUpload />.  Is it supported for this component?  Or only the RichFaces component?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, actionListener does not exist for s:fileUpload. Maybe you can use a converter?